# Random phone number generator for any country

Tags: java, libphonenumber

I am trying to create synthetic data around phone numbers, from a list of countries.

I found Google's [libphonenumber](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber) Java library with ports in Python, C++, etc. a good resource.

Is it possible to generate *valid* random phone numbers from a list of countries, with this library?

With this code I've written, I am using their `getExampleNumber` function but it is generating the same number each time:

```
import com.google.i18n.phonenumbers.PhoneNumberUtil;
import com.google.i18n.phonenumbers.PhoneNumberUtil.PhoneNumberType;
import com.google.i18n.phonenumbers.Phonenumber.PhoneNumber;
import com.google.i18n.phonenumbers.Phonemetadata.PhoneNumberDesc;
import com.google.i18n.phonenumbers.NumberParseException;

public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       // Prints "Hello, World" in the terminal window.
       for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
       {
          System.out.println(Generator());
       }
    }


    public static PhoneNumber  Generator() 
    {
       String regionCode = new String("GB");
       PhoneNumberUtil phoneNumberUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
       PhoneNumber exampleNumber =phoneNumberUtil.getExampleNumber(regionCode);
       return exampleNumber;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to use the REGEX that the library has, somehow, but it's a lot of work.

As the function of getExampleNumber will return you the exact same value, always, you can still use it, to randomize (or iterate) numbers in it.

Here's an example (sample [**here**](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/174302345#comment3)) of how to do it, getting 10 random mobile phone numbers of each supported region :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    @WorkerThread
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val phoneNumbersToRandomize = 10
        var regionsThatFoundMobilePhonesFor = 0
        if (savedInstanceState == null)
            thread {
                val phoneNumberUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance()
                val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
                val supportedRegions = phoneNumberUtil.supportedRegions
                for (region in supportedRegions) {
                    val validPhoneNumbers = HashSet<String>()
                    val exampleNumber = phoneNumberUtil.getExampleNumberForType(region, PhoneNumberUtil.PhoneNumberType.MOBILE)
                    if (exampleNumber == null) {
                        Log.w("AppLog", "region:$region no exampleNumber")
                        continue
                    }
                    Log.d("AppLog", "region:$region exampleNumber:${phoneNumberUtil.format(exampleNumber, PhoneNumberUtil.PhoneNumberFormat.E164)}")
                    val countryCode = phoneNumberUtil.getCountryCodeForRegion(region)
                    val nationalSignificantNumber = phoneNumberUtil.getNationalSignificantNumber(exampleNumber)
                    //                    Log.d("AppLog", "finding $phoneNumbersToRandomize random mobile phone numbers for $region example phone number:" +
                    //                            phoneNumberUtil.format(exampleNumber, PhoneNumberUtil.PhoneNumberFormat.E164) + " countryCode:$countryCode nationalSignificantNumber:$nationalSignificantNumber ")
                    val randomDigitsLength = nationalSignificantNumber.length
                    while (validPhoneNumbers.size < phoneNumbersToRandomize) {
                        val inputPhone = "+$countryCode${getRandomStringOfDigits(randomDigitsLength)}"
                        if (validPhoneNumbers.contains(inputPhone))
                            continue
                        val phoneNumber = phoneNumberUtil.parse(inputPhone, region)
                        val nationalSignificantNumberFromGeneratedNumber = phoneNumberUtil.getNationalSignificantNumber(phoneNumber)
                        if (nationalSignificantNumberFromGeneratedNumber.length != randomDigitsLength)
                            continue
                        val isValidMobilePhoneNumber = phoneNumberUtil.isValidNumberForRegion(phoneNumber, region)
                                && phoneNumberUtil.isPossibleNumberForType(phoneNumber, PhoneNumberUtil.PhoneNumberType.MOBILE)
                        if (isValidMobilePhoneNumber) {
                            validPhoneNumbers.add(inputPhone)
                        }
                    }
                    ++regionsThatFoundMobilePhonesFor
                }
                Log.d("AppLog", "done regionsThatFoundMobilePhonesFor:$regionsThatFoundMobilePhonesFor out of ${supportedRegions.size}" +
                        "timeTaken:${System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime}ms")
            }

    }

    companion object {
        private fun getRandomStringOfDigits(numberOfDigitsToGenerate: Int): String {
            val sb = StringBuilder(numberOfDigitsToGenerate)
            for (i in 0 until numberOfDigitsToGenerate)
                sb.append(Random.nextInt(10).toString())
            return sb.toString()
        }
    }
}
```

gradle dependencies:

```
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    api 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:8.12.13'
```

Answer (score 1):

This library does not provide you with random numbers, no matter how many times you run your code you will always get:

```
Country Code: 44 National Number: 1212345678
```

You can take a look to their github project:

https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber/

And you will see a lot of proto files inside this folder:

https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber/tree/master/java/libphonenumber/src/com/google/i18n/phonenumbers/data

From those files is where they get that number, so it is hardcoded in there. No way to get it randomly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the minimal regex version from [libphonenumber-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/libphonenumber-js) library's metadata and this [tool](https://onlinetools.com/random/generate-random-data-from-regexp) to generate valid random phone number for any country.

If this is too complicated, you can take a look at this [Random phone number generator](https://dotrand.com/phone-numbers/single) to simplify all of these stuffs.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34855311)